# how to git log amendments

Tags: git, gerrit

So basically, I know that to see past git commits, you do git log. But at my company we work with gerrit on one commit and you make amendments to that commits. How do I see all the past amendments to that specific commit, so I see each of their commit message and I can diff between the amendments? THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the amendments have the same `Change-Id`, then thay are patch sets of one change. You don't specify in the question how the diff is displayed, so here's one of the possible solutions.

```
ssh -p <port> <username>@<gerrithost> gerrit query commit:<commit-id> --patch-sets --format=json
```

- `port` is 29418 by default;
- `username` is the gerrit username to run
  `gerrit query`. It should be assinged the right to read the refs of
  the repository;
- `gerrithost` is the the host name or the IP address of your gerrit;
- `commit-id` is the sha1 value of a commit.
- `--format=json` is optional. The default format is `text`.

The output includes details about the patch sets of the change, including entries like:

```
ref: refs/changes/90/812290/3
ref: refs/changes/90/812290/2
ref: refs/changes/90/812290/1
```

These are the refs that Gerrit creates for every commit that is pushed to `refs/for` destination. If you know the number `812290`, you could use `change:812290` to replace `commit:<commit-id>` in the `gerrit query`. Fetch these refs in a local repository:

```
git fetch origin refs/changes/90/812290/3
```

The commits that are pointed at by these refs are downloaded and then you can run git commands to manipulate them as you like.

```
git diff commit1 commit2
```

You could search for `gerrit query` in Gerrit's docs to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, that is not possible.

From [Atlassian's Git Tutorials](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history):

> Amended commits are actually entirely new commits and the previous commit will no longer be on your current branch.

That is, you won't be able to access amended commits.

As an alternative, you could apply all changes as separate commits and when you finished the review **[squash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)** (section: Squashing commits) them using [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all "amendments" have the same *Change-ID*,
(which is how Gerrit associates a set of commits to the same *Gerrit-Change*,
you can choose which versions of a change you would like to compare to each-other.

The default behavior is to compare the **Base** (first commit in the set) to the **latest** one.

In your local (git-)branch, you could also see the different versions of your change
by using the `git reflog` command.

(`git reflog` shows the history of your work like breadcrumbs,
and you can even `show` and `cherry-pick` any of those revisions)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$ git log --reflog` as if all objects mentioned by reflogs are listed on the command line as `commit`.